# Aumentar timeout da conexão dblib com PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Em uma conexão com um servidor externo (**MS SQL SERVER**), de outro sistema com o qual integro alguns dados, está extremamente lento, e com isso a conexão com o banco dá erro.

Como aumentar timeout da conexão **dblib** com **PDO**?

Tentei utilizar `array(\PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 10)` como opção na conexão **PDO** mas gera o seguinte erro:

> Warning: PDO::__construct(): SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support setting attributes in /var/www/core/class/Banco/GkBanco.php on line 25

Como conectar ao `MSSQL` com um timeout maior? pode ser utilizando qualquer lib que funcione com **linux**.

Tentei utilizar `setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 10);`  e gera o seguinte erro:

> Warning: PDO::setAttribute(): SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support setting attributes

Tentei adicionar `ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 30);` antes da conexão não alterou nada.

Comment: Já tentou usar [`PDO::setAttribute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)?

Comment: Também não funciona: Warning: PDO::setAttribute(): SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support setting attributes

Comment: Nesse caso talvez seja necessário usar outro *driver*, usando [`PDO::getAvailableDrivers`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php) retorna os *drivers* disponíveis. Antes de escolher um, verifique se o mesmo suporta o `setAttribute`. Veja a lista de drivers [**aqui**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.drivers.php).

Comment: @stderr, sabendo que PDO_SQLSRV só funciona em servidores Windows, qual outra opção tenho para conexão com MSSQL Server ?

Comment: Segundo a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php#ref.pdo-sqlsrv.installation), a opção é [**PDO_ODBC**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-odbc.php), veja também essa página na [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh568451(v=sql.110).aspx) para mais detalhes.

Comment: Tenta colocar `ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 10);` antes da conexão.

Comment: @Augusto, agradeço pela ajuda, mas não mudou nada.

Answer (score 3):

Tente isso aqui

```
$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, 5);
```

OU

Você também pode tentar adicionar na connection string

```
$pdo = new \PDO("sqlsrv:Server=server;Database=dbname;LoginTimeout=5", 'username', 'password');
```

mais informações: http://php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar

```
$pdoConnection->setAttribute(\PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, 10);
```

Porém você pode inserir isso diretamente na query string de conexão com a sua base de dados.

Exemplo com mysql:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;timeout', $user, $pass);
```

Você achará mais referências inclusive para outras bases na documentação oficial do php.

Segue o link:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.connections.php

Comment: SQL Server não MySQL.

Comment: Amigo, foi um exemplo, você muda a string de conexão conforme sua necessidade.